# Optimizing my solution for 1D peg solitaire

Tags: python, algorithm

First I will explain the rules of peg solitaire (for 1 dimension):
you initially start with a 1 dimensional board of length n. n-1 elements are pegs (filled) and 1 element is a hole (empty). So a starting position can be `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` where 1s represent pegs and 0s represent holes for `n = 6`

The goal of the game is to reach a board state where n-1 elements are holes and 1 element is a peg at any given position. So a valid solution can be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` for `n = 6`

Your available moves at any given position is to move one peg by two positions to the right or to the left if and only if there is a peg between the two position, then once you make that move, replace the middle peg with a hole.

So for a board such as `board = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]` there are two available moves.

1. move `board[1]` to `board[3]` and set `board[2] = 0`
2. move `board[5]` to `board[3]` and set `board[4] = 0`
3. move `board[2]` to `board[0]` and set `board[1] = 0`
4. move `board[4]` to `board[6]` and set `board[5] = 0`

The goal of the algorithm I am trying to make is to take an input of n where n > 2 and n is an even number, then for a board of length n, find all the positions for a start state at which a hole can be placed to produce a valid solution.

I have created a brute force algorithm which finds all the possible moves until a valid solution is reached, but it starts taking a very long time to find a solution past n > 20. So I was wondering if there are some optimizations I could do or different solution approaches.

Here is my code:

```
import re

def generateBoard(n):
    return [1]*n

def solve(board):
    if checkBoard(board):
        return True
    elif checkUnsolvable(board):
        return False

    moves = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if i < len(board)-2:
            if board[i] and board[i+1] and not board[i+2]:
                moves.append((i, 'right'))
        if i > 1:
            if board[i] and board[i-1] and not board[i-2]:
                moves.append((i, 'left'))
    
    for move in moves:
        newBoard = makeMove(board, move)
        if solve(newBoard):
            return True
        continue

    return False


def makeMove(board, move):
    index, direction = move
    b = [element for element in board]
    if direction == 'right':
        b[index] = 0
        b[index+1] = 0
        b[index+2] = 1
    elif direction == 'left':
        b[index] = 0
        b[index-1] = 0
        b[index-2] = 1
    return b

def checkBoard(board):
    if sum(board) == 1:
        return True
    return False

def checkUnsolvable(board):
    expression1 = '1000+1' #RE for a proven to be unsolvable board
    expression2 = '00100'  #RE for a proven to be unsolvable board
    string = ''.join([str(element) for element in board])
    if re.search(expression1, string) or re.search(expression2, string):
        return True
    return False

def countSolutions(board):
    indices = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        b = [element for element in board]
        b[i] = 0
        if solve(b):
            indices.append(i+1)
    return indices


n = int(input())
print(countSolutions(generateBoard(n)))
```

Optimizations I have come up with so far:

1. A board containing `[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1]` is unsolvable. So when we find this patters we skip
2. Same thing for a board containing `[0, 0, .. 0, 1, 0, 0, ..,0]`
3. We only need to check half of the board, as the solutions of the other half would be symmetrical.

But despite these the code is still very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm for doing the solitaire is covered in this research paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0006067.pdf.

It claims that a linear time algorithm exists.

---

A valid solution looks like this:

> ```py
> L = 1
>  or 011
>  or 110
>  or 11 (01)* [ 00 | 00(11)+ | (11)+00 | (11)*1011 | 1101(11)* ] (10)*11  # (A)
>  or 11 (01)* (11)* 01  # (B)
>  or 10 (11)* (10)* 11  # (C)
> ```

---

To solve A, you can use regex to check for the string. However, there are multiple cases of it due to the middle section.

First case: `11(01)*00(10)*11`
Second case: `11(01)*(00)(11)+(10)*11`
Third case: `11(01)*(11)+(00)(10)*11`
Fourth case: `11(01)*(11)*(1011)(10)*11`
Fifth case: `11(01)*1101(11)*(10)*11`

---

To solve B and C is a simpler regex match:

Solution for B: `11(01)*(11)*01`
Solution for C: `10(11)*(10)*11`

---

If you match (you will need to convert it to a string though, such as `''.join([str(i) for i in mylist])` for example) `1`, `011`, `110`, or any of the patterns above, then it will be solvable.

Comment: Thanks. This does answer my question but I am wondering if there could be a normal search algorithm other than brute force.

Comment: This technically isn’t a brute force search, but a property that every solvable configuration has. If you look at how the regex is generated, you can see how to solve them (`110->001, 011->100`)

Comment: I was talking about my solution being a bruteforce backtracking approach not the regular expression method

Comment: I don’t understand. This is the fastest algorithm I know of, it’s basically O(N)

Comment: What I mean is the RE method is fine but I was wondering if there was any other way to solve it other than the solution I provided

Comment: The entire way it generates the solution is to play the game in reverse, so if you look at how the regex is made you can see how to make the substitutions. You start at 1011 or 1101.